# How should I use IAM Role to access S3 in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, roles

I met an issue when I tried to use IAM Role to Access S3 in C#. Below is the steps I've done.

1. Create STS AssumeRole Policy:
   {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
           "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::761612772509:role/S3TestRole",
           "Condition": {
               "StringEquals": {
                   "aws:RequestedRegion": "ap-northeast-1"
               }
           }
       }
   ]
   }
2. Create an IAM Role(AWS Other Account) and attached the  AssumeRole Policy to this role:
   Role ARN: arn:aws:iam::761612772509:role/S3TestRole
   And Trust Relationship is as pic show:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWFfc.png)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvor5.png)
3. Active STS Region:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r5I3.png)
4. S3 Bucket Policy:
   {
   "Id": "Policy1573183227944",
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Sid": "Stmt1573183224129",
           "Action": "s3:*",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:s3:::20190830s3bucket",
               "arn:aws:s3:::20190830s3bucket/*"
           ],
           "Principal": {
               "AWS": [
                   "arn:aws:iam::761612772509:role/S3TestRole"
               ]
           }
       }
   ]
   }

```
   try
            {
                AssumeRoleRequest assumeRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest
                {
                    RoleArn = "arn:aws:iam::761612772509:role/S3TestRole",
                    DurationSeconds = 3600,
                    Policy = "{\"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\": [{\"Sid\": \"VisualEditor0\",\"Effect\": \"Allow\",\"Action\": \"sts:AssumeRole\",\"Resource\": \"arn:aws:iam::761612772509:role/S3TestRole\",\"Condition\": {\"StringEquals\": {\"aws:RequestedRegion\": \"ap-northeast-1\"}}}]}",
                };


                AssumeRoleResult assumeRoleResult = new AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.APNortheast1).AssumeRole(assumeRequest);


                AWSCredentials tempCredentials = new SessionAWSCredentials(
                   assumeRoleResult.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
                   assumeRoleResult.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
                   assumeRoleResult.Credentials.SessionToken);
                s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(tempCredentials);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

My region is in ap-northeast-1, and when execute the assumeRoleResult method, I always got"The security token included in the request is invalid." and InnerException is "The remote server returned an error: (403) forbidden." errors. May I know what's wrong with my configuration or code? Appreciate for your help in advance!

Comment: Make sure STS is activated for that region. See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_enable-regions.html

Comment: Yes, I activated the STS in this region, and also add one region request condition in the Policy. But seems the error still exist...